# UIScrollView and sliding images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have an array `imageNames`

```
NSArray *imageNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", nil];
```

I want to display the first image in a `UIScrollView` and then change it when make an horizontal slide.

.h code:

```
@interface SlidePViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{       
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;  
    UIImageView *imageView; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

and i founded this code which is supposed to do the job

```
for(NSString *imageName in imageNames){
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    image.frame = CGRectMake([imageNames indexOf:imageName] * SCREENWIDTH, 0, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
    [scrollView addSubview:image];
    [image release];
}
```

I changed SCREENWIDTH and SCREENWIDTH ... with numbers

```
image.frame = CGRectMake([imageNames indexOf:imageName] * 100, 0, 11, 888);
```

Error:

> invalid operand to binary expression('id' and 'int')

I am not sure that this code will do what i want :/

**UPDATE** 
i change the line by this

```
image.frame = CGRectMake([imageNames indexOfObject:imageName] * 1000, 0, 1100, 888);
```

Error is fixed but i can not make a sliding , the first image is displayed in the UIScrollView and it don't change with an horizontal slide .

Comment: I think that error does not due to setting frame

Comment: Which line are you noticing this error?

Comment: this line image.frame = CGRectMake([imageNames indexOf:imageName] * 100, 0, 11, 888);

Comment: @Mehdi The problem you are having is that you are just copying and pasting code together without taking the time to work out what the code is doing. This is not a good way to learn. You aren't showing any code related to the UIScrollView either. I suggest you go and read the Apple documentation relating to UIScrollView rather than hoping someone will write more code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe error in below line.

```
image.frame = CGRectMake([imageNames indexOf:imageName] * SCREENWIDTH, 0, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
```

In above try `image.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);`

If execute it without error that means you need to change in frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
image.frame = CGRectMake([imageNames indexOfObject:imageName] * 100, 0, 11, 888);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf:` method doesn't exist in the NSArray documentation, you should try calling:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
```